# Redefining a year to group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have some price data as timeseries. I am trying to group and average prices by year and month. Here's the catch, I want to have a year go from Jul-Jun e.g. year 2015 would be Jul 2015 - Jun 2016 (defined as Crop Year) Therefore 'Crop Month' also needs to go 1-12 for Jul-Jun. Is there anyway to achieve this is pandas. The logic in my code seems flawed and doesn't give me the result I want. I tried using a loop with some if statements but my logic got lost somewhere. I have posted the resulting dataframe below. As you can see the crop year data is wrong. Any help with how to approach the code would be great.

´´´

```
pxdata = ek.get_timeseries(['Wc1','BL2c1', 'W13.5-FOBRU=AGRP'], fields='CLOSE', start_date='2009-01-01')

pxdata.loc[:,'Crop Month'] = 0
pxdata.loc[:,'Crop Year'] = 0
pxdata.iloc[0,-1] = 2015
pxdata.iloc[0,-2] = 8
for i in range(1, len(pxdata)):
    if pxdata.index[i].month==7:
        pxdata.iloc[i,-2]=1
    elif pxdata.index[i].month>pxdata.index[i-1].month:
        pxdata.iloc[i,-2]=pxdata.iloc[i-1,-2]+1
    else:
        pxdata.iloc[i,-2]=pxdata.iloc[i-1,-2]
    if pxdata.iloc[i-1,-2]==12 and pxdata.iloc[i,-2]==1 :
        pxdata.iloc[i,-1]=pxdata.iloc[i-1,-1]+1
    else:
        pxdata.iloc[i,-1]=pxdata.iloc[i-1,-1]
```

´´´

Thanks in advance, guys

[image]

Comment: please post real code and data, not images.

Comment: Question, does subtracting six months from your date work for your query?   Dec 27, 2019 becomes Crop Month 6 in year 2019, and Jan 3, 2020 becomes Crop Month 7 in year 2019?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set your Date as index, so you can use `dataframe.loc['2015-07-01':'2016-06-01']` to select your data.

[pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Then create a date-range for your time series which you want to select.

`start = pd.date_range('2015-06-01', periods=4, freq='12M')
end = pd.date_range('2016-07-01', periods=4, freq='12M')
for start, end in list(zip(start,end)):
    print(start, end)`

[pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

Now you can select the period by `loc[start:end]`.

If you want to select average values, you can use `dataframe.mean()`.

[pandas.DataFrame.mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

Good luck.